# purpose of the *result ="" * in the following code

Tags: python, string

I am trying to understand `result=" "` statement in this code. This code is for creating acronym .

```
def initials(phrase):
    words = phrase.split()
    **result = ""**
    for word in words:
        result += word[0]
    return result.upper()
```

Comment: `result = ""` just creates an empty string, what is your specific question?

Comment: Just comment out the line and see what happens. You’ll figure it out

Answer (score 5):

```
result += word[0]
```

This is (roughly) equivalent to

```
result = result + word[0]
```

Now, if we omit the `result = ""` line, then this is

```
result = <thing that doesn't exist> + word[0]
```

which is an error. We need to *initialize* `result` to a starting value, and an empty phrase has an empty acronym, so `""` is a good candidate

Answer (score 0):

We need some place to stick our initial letters. This line initializes the variable `result` so that the data can be put there. While Python isn't as strongly typed as other languages such as C, `+=` has different definitions for different types/classes, so assigning `result` an empty string tells Python that it should use `+=` that's defined for strings. However, a more Pythonic way of doing this would be

```
def initials(phrase):
    words = phrase.split()
    result = "".join(word[0] for word in words)
    return result.upper()
```

This tells Python that we want to join the first letters together, and the empty string says that we don't want any spaces in between them. If we wanted a space between each letter, we would have `result = " ".join(word[0] for word in words)`.